# await inside a WPF Dispatcher call

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

What is the best solution to ensure errorhandling when awating inside a delegate that is pased to the dispatcher?

In short: I need to return a number after parsing a calculation to Foo. That calculation is very slow and have to be done on the UI thread. The calculation must be handed to another class as a `Task<string>`.

The only solution I could come up with was CallFooWithATask___3 - and not even sure about that..

```
public class Foo
{
    public void CallMeWithATaskThatIsFinishedWhenTheUIIsUpdated(Task<string> task) { }
}

// CallFooWithATask___ is invoked from unknown thread. Can't wait for GetWithSideEffects on calling thread
public class SomeClass
{
    private TextBox textBox;

    public int CallFooWithATask___1(Foo foo)
    {
        // not good - async void -> no error handling
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
        {                
            var a = await GetWithSideEffects();
            textBox.Text = a;
            tcs.SetResult(a);
        });

        // quite fast - probally put it in a queue and returns
        foo.CallMeWithATaskThatIsFinishedWhenTheUIIsUpdated(tcs.Task);

        return 1;
    }

    public async Task<int> CallFooWithATask___2(Foo foo)
    {
        // not good - still async void  -> no error handling .. when is foo actually called? I assume when hitting the inner await'ish?
        var task =  await Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            var a = await GetWithSideEffects();
            textBox.Text = a;
            return a;
        });

        // quite fast - probally put it in a queue and returns
        foo.CallMeWithATaskThatIsFinishedWhenTheUIIsUpdated(task);

        return 1;
    }

    public int CallFooWithATask___3(Foo foo)
    {
        // what is the elegant solution - probally not this?
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var a = await GetWithSideEffects();
                textBox.Text = a;
                tcs.SetResult(a);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { tcs.SetException(ex); }
        });

        // quite fast - probally put it in a queue and returns
        foo.CallMeWithATaskThatIsFinishedWhenTheUIIsUpdated(tcs.Task);

        return 1;
    }

    // this might trigger ui updates and is very slow ..
    private Task<string> GetWithSideEffects()=> Task.FromResult("42");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the best solution to ensure errorhandling when awating inside a delegate that is pased to the dispatcher.

Comment: In general, I recommend structuring code so that the UI calls the logic, not the logic calling the UI. The UI shouldn't be providing services to the logic. If the logic needs a service, then define an interface for it and then the UI can implement that interface, using `SynchronizationContext` if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. Just extract your async code in a method or in a `Func<Task<string>>` to avoid ending with an `async void`:

```
Func<Task<string>> func = async () =>
{
    var a = await GetWithSideEffects();

    return a;
};
```

Then invoke it with `InvokeAsync`. You'll end up with a `Task<Task<string>>`. The inner task is the one returned by your async method, the outer task is the one generated by `InvokeAsync` to indicate when the call is actually dispatched.
Use `.Unwrap` to merge those tasks, and finally send them to your other method:

```
var task = Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(func).Task.Unwrap();

foo.CallMeWithATaskThatIsFinishedWhenTheUIIsUpdated(task);
```